# javascript troubleshooting in canvas using console.log

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to troubleshoot some javascript code, but I can't get any console.log info to show up on the html canvas so that I can see the values of my variables. Is there a basic way of doing this?

```js
// JavaScript Document
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
console.log("Hello world!");
alert("Just executed this code!");
```

```css
canvas {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; 
    left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   background: rgba(10,10,153,0.5);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title>Art01a2020</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste some of your code please :)

Comment: That's better, thanks. Do you know how to use the dev tools and console in your browser?

Comment: No, will research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log don't log things in the canvas, it will output on explorer's developer console `F12`, if you want to debug things in the canvas, you could use the [fillText method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp) to output a text with a variable on your canvas.

example:

```
ctx.fillText(some_variable, screen_x_position, screen_y_position);
```

Comment: How come when I type ctx.fillText("Hello World", 10,10); into the above javascript code I still can't see anything?